# Wet grout outside the shower

Tags: plumbing, shower, leak

This is a newly installed shower. We first time used it two months after it was done and we discovered that the grout outside the shower gets wet every time we use it.

It's the corner where the shower glass frame meets the wall and the floor.

I had my bathroom installer back three times to reseal all around the tray.
However it still gets wet. Drys quick too but it has about like 10cm bleed and it also goes the tray direction, the grout underneath the white sealant outside the tray.

I suspect the water gets in between the frame and the wall, there's a small channel where I circled in the first picture when the silicone is removed. so I assume the water still gets in there.

However, the silicone inside looks OK?? (second picture) but I'm not ruling out that it's **** silicone job. He did the white silicone around the tray in one visit and the clear one along the bottom and the door was done in another visit.. and they looks messy.]

I now tempted to do it myself even though it's free to get him back to do it but he was like 'surely that's it now, we redid all the seals' and he also said that I don't need to panic about it because it's tiny tiny water.

Or can it be the water travels through the grout from the tile inside? (circled up in the third picture).

Anyway, it's stressing me out that I can't find where the leak is from.
Please help[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: That looks like the worst sealing job I  have seen. It is most probably the seal

Comment: @RohitGupta lol yeah it's not great.. is it.. I just realised that I missed out an image of the inside corner. Will you remove all around the tray and redo it or just the ugly corner and the clear ones?

Comment: New silicone doesn't stick to old silicone so if you're redoing it all the old stuff has to be off.  You can't just add more.  The seal on the inside is the one that you want, doesn't matter how crappy the outside seal looks.  Water will get absorbed by grout but it looks sealed up on the inside and the grout line above is dry.

Comment: @aquaticapetheory ok, so can I guess that's why my plumber's sealing job gone wrong? he's done the inside silicone in different visits. Along the frame looks ok but the bottom corner and along the glass looks messy.

Comment: The sealing job might be fine at the bottom but if there's an opening in the sealant above that somewhere then water would get in, run down to the bottom, and show up soaking out through the grout.  You can experiment by spraying water higher and higher up letting things thoroughly dry between each time and seeing when you get that wet mark below.

Comment: @aquaticapetheory ah! yes! I will give a go! Thank you!